# Pattern matching Postgres to replace misspelled words of a column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table A :

| name | renamed_name |
| --- | --- |
| HON/A |  |
| HONDA TRUCK |  |
| GMC |  |

and I have a renaming rules table B:

| rule | correct_name |
| --- | --- |
| HON/A | HONDA |
| HONDA TRUCK | HONDA |
| ^GMC.+ | GMC |

I need to update table A and set the column A.renamed_name to the B.correct_name of Table B where A.name matched any of B.rule.

When I use the following update query:

`Update A set A.renamed_name = B.correct_name from B where name ~* any(array[B.rule])` gives me a result

| name | renamed_name |
| --- | --- |
| HON/A | HONDA |
| HONDA TRUCK | HONDA |
| GMC | NULL |

The last row is not updated though my condition check includes regex exp. Please let me know where I can be possibly going wrong or if there is an alternate solution.

Comment: `GMC` doesn't match `^GMC.+`. Have a look at [regex101](https://regex101.com), i find it really useful.

Comment: Thanks it indeed doesn't match! I am editing my question again. What I need is if the A.name does not match any of B.rule, then A.renamed_name = A.name else apply the rule. The update query works for some but not for all.